# How to submit information for an unknown nmap service when nmap does not provide the fingerprint?

Tags: networking, nmap

I have a device which runs some embedded code (I know what exactly runs there) but `nmap` does not recognize it:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
8266/tcp open  unknown
```

I would be glad to provide the exact details but no fingerprint is available from `nmap`.

Is there a way to force a fingerprint to be displayed? Or is it that there must be some specific conditions for a service to be recognizable at all? (in which case no fingerprint = the service will not be recognized no matter what)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Submitting a new fingerprint to Nmap](https://nmap.org/book/vscan-community.html) requires that Nmap receives a response to one of its service probes. If no response is received to any probe, it will not print a fingerprint. From the output banner you showed, you are running `nmap -sV` to send these service probes, since the banner has the "VERSION" heading. So what you need to do is ensure that Nmap sends a probe which will elicit a response from your service.

One way to attempt this is to use the `--version-all` option, which is an alias for `--version-intensity=9`. This ensures that all defined service probes will be attempted against unidentified services, even if they are very unlikely to provoke a response. If this does not work, you may need to define a service probe yourself.

Service probes are defined in the `nmap-service-probes` file and have the format `Probe TCP nameOfProbe q|probe bytes here|`. If you know the protocol, you should be able to come up with a probe which will elicit a response. Our design goals for service probes are:

1. Do not negatively impact the service being probed, e.g. crash or cause it to shut down.
2. Elicit a response that provides some information about the software running the service, e.g. a "version" API request or handshake message which elicits a server banner.
3. Avoid state changes which would cause concern to a sysadmin, e.g. login attempts, exploiting vulnerabilities.

If your new service probe works to get Nmap to print a service fingerprint, then submit it as [an issue on Github](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/new) or send it to the dev@nmap.org mailing list.

Comment: Thank you, the `--version-all` switch finally yield a fingerprint, though a small one (and what is mentioned inside is not related to the service). I will submit it right away.